# Why Go compiler needs to only include the packages that you are importing directly?

Tags: go, compiler-optimization

I have been using Go and have read at some places that Go compiler needs to only include the packages that you are importing directly from `main`.
As a result, the time it takes to resolve dependency is linear as compared to C++ where its exponential.
How does that work?
If `main` imports package `alpha` which in turn imports package `beta` then wouldn't Go compiler need to compile the whole tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go compiler first compiles a single package into a single object file. At this stage, it only needs to resolve all the `import`s it finds in the package it compiles. For the object file of your package, there are only calls to the same package or direct imports, so there's no issue here. A separate linking stage links all object files together. There's a decent explanation of this in the [doc of the compile package](https://golang.org/cmd/compile/):

> Compile, typically invoked as “go tool compile,” compiles a single Go
>   package comprising the files named on the command line. It then writes
>   a single object file named for the basename of the first source file
>   with a .o suffix. The object file can then be combined with other
>   objects into a package archive or passed directly to the linker (“go
>   tool link”). If invoked with -pack, the compiler writes an archive
>   directly, bypassing the intermediate object file.
>
> The generated files contain type information about the symbols
>   exported by the package and about types used by symbols imported by
>   the package from other packages. It is therefore not necessary when
>   compiling client C of package P to read the files of P's dependencies,
>   only the compiled output of P.

Comment: When does it compile the transitive dependencies to generate their object files?

Comment: @SauravPrakash: these dependencies are discovered because there's an `import` to them from somewhere, so they are added to the build, and so on...

Comment: doesnt that again mean compiling the whole tree eventually?

Comment: @SauravPrakash: yes, absolutely, unless it has already been compiled. Obviously, if you program depends on `A` and `A` depends on `B`, you will need `B` in your final binary, there's no other way around it! But you don't need `B` to compile and type-check 'main` itself, you only need it to compile and type-check `A`. Since most dependencies are cached and don't change, in a regular edit-compile cycle you usually compile just one package, which is why Go builds are so fast

Comment: If you *absolutely* need to import a package in order to like get its initializer to run and nothing else is going to import it you can do something like: import _ "github.com/jwells131313/dargo/ioc"